# What is an active CentOS6 / RHEL6 repository providing icinga?

Tags: centos6, repository, rhel6, icinga

There are several CentOS6 repositories listed in the wiki and I checked nearly all of them. Only RPMForge provides icinga / icinga-web, but in v1.7.2 which is fairly outdated and contains several bugs. (e.g. status map not working with child/parent hosts) I do know that I just could compile it myself, but that would make it quite harder to maintain and keep up-to-date.

Are there any other CentOS6 / RHEL6 repos that offer newer versions of icinga-web?

Comment: Did you check the [EPEL repository](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL)?

Comment: http://pkgs.org is a good overview for questions like that.

Comment: Why not create your own rpm package using [fpm](https://github.com/jordansissel/fpm) and put it into the local repository?

Comment: @ewwhite yes, unfortunately [they don't feature icinga](http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/x86_64/repoview/letter_i.group.html) in EPEL.

Comment: @SvenW that list is huge, but looking through them still couldn't find satisfying results.

Comment: @quanta I guess your solution is similar to the one of Michael Hampton. I tried to avoid that, but I guess I need to build my own. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not long ago I went looking for Icinga RPM packages, and could not find a repository (that looked reputable) containing them, so I went to build them myself. Fortunately `icinga` and `icinga-web` contain their own spec files which you can use as a starting point:

```
rpmbuild -ts icinga-1.8.*.tar.gz
rpmbuild -ts icinga-web-1.8.*.tar.gz

mock -r epel-6-x86_64 ~/rpmbuild/SRPMS/icinga-1.8.*.src.rpm
mock -r epel-6-x86_64 ~/rpmbuild/SRPMS/icinga-web-1.8.*.src.rpm
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick writeup. I guess I need to go with your solution as there are no other solutions offered. :)